# Should I dispose transient object provided by IServiceProvider or the garbage collector takes care of it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm building an tournament app in which there are of course lots of tournaments to play. I am getting a TournamentStore object from built in dependency injection in ASP.NET Core 3.1.

In Startup.cs, in ConfigureServices method I'm setting a transient service:

```
services.AddTransient<ITournamentStore, TournamentStore>();
```

and I'm getting that service by injecting IServiceProvider in constructor of TournamentService class:

```
public class TournamentService : ITournamentService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public TournamentService(
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task<ITournamentStore> GetRandomTournamentAsync(DateTime startTime)
    {
        var tournament = (ITournamentStore)_serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITournamentStore));
        // add tournament details...
```

in TournamentStore (the service I'm getting from IServiceProvider) I'm using System.Timers.Timer which should be disposed:

```
public class TournamentStore : ITournamentStore, IAsyncDisposable, IDisposable
{
    private Timer _timer;

    private readonly ITournamentsStore _tournaments;
    private readonly IHubContext<GameHub, IGameClient> _hubContext;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public TournamentStore(
        ITournamentsStore tournaments,
        IHubContext<GameHub, IGameClient> hubContext,
        IMapper mapper)
    {
        _tournaments = tournaments;
        _hubContext = hubContext;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public string PublicId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string TypeId { get; set; }
    public string Difficulty { get; set; }
    public string DifficultyId { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionModel> Questions { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfQuestions => Questions.Count();
    public int SecondsPerQuestion { get; set; } = 15;
    public int CurrentQuestion { get; set; } = 0;
    public bool Finshed => CurrentQuestion > Questions.Count();
    public bool Public { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public string StartTimeWithTimeZone => StartTime.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'");
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPlayers => Players.Count();

    public void SetTournamentStartTimer()
    {
        var difference = StartTime - DateTime.UtcNow;
        _timer = new Timer(difference.TotalMilliseconds);
        _timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await StartTournamentAsync();
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private async Task StartTournamentAsync()
    {
        // some logic to start tournament

    }

    public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

So I'm wondering should I dispose complete object or just Timer in DisposeAsync method and let the garbage collector takes care of TournamentStore object?
As you can see the  TournamentStore object is composed of several properties and two lists of objects, so should I set those lists to null if I am disposing TournamentStore object?
The DisposeAsync would be called from object itself if there are not enough of players or tournament finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class requesting an ITournamentStore from the service provider doesn't know the scope of the object (singleton, transient, ...), so the disposing of TournamentStore should be managed by the ServiceProvider.

All the disposable properties of TournamentStore should be disposed on TournamentStore disposing.
There is no need to set all the properties to null.

I advice to not implement both interfaces IDisposable and IAsyncDisposable.
The Dispose or DisposeAsync method is intended to be called by the object which created the TournamentStore (here it is the ServiceProvider).

I would recommend to use an implementation like bellow:

```
private async Task<ITournament> StartTournamentAsync()
```

With

```
ITournament : IAsyncDisposable
```

Comment: So I should only dispose a Timer?

Comment: yes, as the Timer is the only disposable object created by the TournamentStore.
Be carefull as you create a new Timer each time you call SetTournamentStartTimer.
The _timer property should be readonly and created on constructor to avoid having multiple timers created.